# AssertJ how to compare two list by their element value?

Tags: java, assertj

Suppose I have a list of `User` *userList*.

```java
class User {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
}
```

Is there a way I can compare using `AssertJ` like

> `assertThat(userList).lastName.equalsTo(List.of("A","B","C"));`

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```java
List<User> users = Arrays.asList(
        new User("a", "A"),
        new User("b", "B"),
        new User("c", "C"));

assertThat(users)
        .extracting(User::getLastName)
        .containsExactly("A", "B", "C");
```

Comment: `extracting` also accepts function so `extracting(User::getLastName)` would work too and is more refactoring friendly.